# How to empty the current row of a DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewrow

I am developing a windows form application for a Books Store. In this application have a datagridview to select books for sale. If there are no items available in the stock I need to clear the current row values.So how can I do this. I tried this

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

But this clear entire datagridview. But I need to clear only current row when I click ok the message.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use removeat by first checking to ensure something is selected and then do a removeat while passing the index.

```
if(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index > -1 && !dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].IsNewRow)
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index);
```

EDIT: Added a check for IsNewRow in case AllowUsersToAddRows is True which would throw and exception if that was the selected row.

Comment: Thank you.This worked.It is simple and easy.thank you once again

Comment: @Kith Make sure you add the second check that I added in my last edit since your datagridview has the NewRow enabled.

Comment: But this still throw an exception if my selected row changed to newRow

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the row in the datagrid that you want to delete. You can do this by selecting the "index" of the row which is selected.

```
dataGrid.Rows[index].Selected = true;
```

or you could do the following:

```
dataGrid.SelectedRows.Clear();
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.Rows)
{
    if(YOUR CONDITION)
       row.Selected = true;
}
```